# Longest String Palindrome Using string.reverse

Tags: java, string

I have been trying to solve a problem of finding longest palindrome of a String.
Though I am able to do it by going to middle element but i wanted to try it through string.reverse :

Here is my code :

Doubt : I am using string.reverse to find the reverse of the given string and Then trying to compare each and every substring in reversed string and input string, but this will not give me largest palindrome but it will give all the possible palindromes...
Also I am doing some mistake somewhere, kindly help me to find that...

```
public class StringPalindrome {    
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("Shubham");
     StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("");
     a = strBuilder.reverse(); //Reverse the string and saving it into other string
     for(int i=0;i<strBuilder.length();i++){ // Loop one for begin index
        for(int j=1;i<strBuilder.length() + 1;j++){  // Loop two for end index
           if(a.substring(i, j).equals(strBuilder.substring(i, j))){ // comparing 
           System.out.println(strBuilder.substring(i, j)); //printing palindrome
           }     
        }    
    }
}
```

I am not able to think to How to find longest Palindrome ?

I think by using string.reverse, it will be a short code :

Though I am able to do it this way :

```
public class LongestPalindrome 
{

static public String expand(String string, int a, int b) 
{
if (a > b)
return null;
int left = a, right = b;
while (left >= 0 && right < string.length() && string.charAt(left) == string.charAt(right)) 
{
left--;
right++;
}
return string.substring(left + 1, right);
}

static public String longestPalindrome(String string) 
{
if (string == null)
return null;
String longest = string.substring(0, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < string.length() - 1; i++) 
{
String palindrome = expand(string, i, i);
if (palindrome.length() > longest.length()) 
{
longest = palindrome;
}
palindrome = expand(string, i, i + 1);
if (palindrome.length() > longest.length()) 
{
longest = palindrome;
}
}
return longest;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println(longestPalindrome("baraik"));
}

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And what is your definition of "longest palindrome of a String"? I can't make heads or tails of that loop, but your code has a lot of issues. The "longest palindrome of a string" to me just means reversing the input string and tacking it onto the end of the original...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Are you people here to help or monk other... ??
My problem is simple... I cudn't find a way to find longest plaindrome rather I am just able to find palindrome....

Comment: can you explain the output you are expecting?

Comment: @PawanMishra I am trying to find largest palindrome...

For e.g. ajajnitin then i then I want to get largest palindrome i.e. nitin as output...

Comment: @ShubhamKumar: I'm not mocking. It's genuinely unclear what your question is. In fact, as of that comment, you hadn't *asked* a question. I try to help people when I can (I've answered more than 5,000 questions), but your initial question (and even the edit) ***seems to*** boil down to "please debug/write this code for me," which isn't what SO is for. That probably isn't what you really mean, so explain why you think the code should work. Explain what it is about it that is confusing you.

Comment: Try writing out the word your trying to analyse backwards and spot the mistake :) (Hint: Try with aaabba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found out that you were looking for the longest palindrome in a string. 
Observe the base case for a palindrome for

For any given index **i**(which progresses from 0 to end of the string) and **j**(which progresses from end of the string to 0)

1. Indices of j and i are equal. They are obviously equal. Single character strings are palindromes.
2. Indices of i and j differ by exactly 1. ie. You are comparing consecutive characters. If they are equal you have found a 2 character palindrome.
3. Else we have 2 ways to go to step `1` or `2`.

   1. Consider string from index[i, j - 1]
   2. Consider string from index[i + 1, j]

   Max of the above 2 conditions gives you the length of the longest palindrome.
4. Memoize steps 1, 2, 3 to get the values from a cache.

   Here is a sample implementation which prints all the palindromes. This is O(n**2).

   ```
   public static int maxPalindrome(char ch[], int i, int j, int cache[][]) {
      if (cache[i][j] != -1) {
          return cache[i][j];
      }

      if (i == j) {
          return cache[i][j] = 1;
      }

      if (j - i  == 1) {
          return cache[i][j] = (ch[i] == ch[j] ? 2 : 0);
      }

      int max = 0;
      //easy if they are equal
      if (ch[i] == ch[j]) {
          int inCount = maxPalindrome(ch, i + 1, j - 1, cache);
           max = inCount == 0 ? 0 : 2 + inCount;
      } 
      //there are 2 ways to go step 3
      maxPalindrome(ch, i + 1, j, cache);

      maxPalindrome(ch, i, j - 1, cache);
      return cache[i][j] = max;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "abbzbasddeeaaaccffertrecca"; 
       char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
       int cache[][] = new int[ch.length][ch.length];
       for (int row[] : cache) {
           Arrays.fill(row, -1);
       }
       maxPalindrome(ch, 0, ch.length - 1, cache);
       //print all the pallindromes
       for (int i = 0; i < cache.length; ++i) {
           for (int j = 0; j < cache.length; ++j) {
               if (cache[i][j] > 0) {
                   System.out.println(str.substring(i, j+1) + " " + cache[i][j]);
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Returns

```
bb 2
bzb 3
z 1
dd 2
ee 2
aa 2
aaa 3
a 1
aa 2
cc 2
ff 2
ertre 5
rtr 3
t 1
cc 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StringPalindrome {    
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       int big=0;
       String pstr ="";
       StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("aabbccabbabhhakllkjiooijpawan-nawap");
        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
            for(int j=i+1;j<str.length();j++){
                if(str.charAt(i)== str.charAt(j) && pldrm(str.subSequence(i,j+1).toString()) && big<(j-i)){
                            pstr=str.subSequence(i,j+1).toString();
                            big=j-i;
                            }
            }
        System.out.println(pstr);
           } 
    static boolean pldrm(String str){
        int length=str.length()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            if(str.charAt(i)!= str.charAt(length-i))
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }   
}
```

output is
    `pawan-nawap`